# Different routes same component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to achieve something like this `/products` shows all the products and `/products/:category` shows all the products related to a specific category. To achieve that I have the following routes:

```js
const productsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ProductsListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':category',
        component: ProductsListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Problem**

When I switch between categories, everything is fine, when I switch between all products and category products, and vice-versa, Angular redraws the components and there's a flickering.

Angular 2 Router final version doesn't have Regex,as for as I know. Is there something that I'm missing, or for now this is the only solution?

Comment: For this case the closest thing I was able to find is the one here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899090/angular2-route-redirect-can-i-use-redirectto-to-parameter-path


There is kind of similar scenario here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41931088/2911817

Comment: You can do this with a path matcher function instead of specifying a static path: See https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391974/1751497

Answer (score 28):

you can solve it by adding routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'experience',
        children: [
            { path: 'pending', component: ExperienceComponent },
            { path: 'requests', component: ExperienceComponent },
        ] }]
```

and in ExperienceComponent import

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

and in constructor add this parameter

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute)
```

and inside constructor get url

```
this.route.url.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params[0].path);
})
```

Comment: This worked for me and then to figure out which path I ended up at, I used the ActivateRoute with if(this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.path == 'pending')

Comment: Thank you! The trick was to NOT have a Component assigned to the base route, but instead assign a new child route with `path: ''` and the Component set, in addition to the `:id` child route. This solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if there is another way to do this but I managed to make it work using the following hack.

```
export const productsRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'products',
        component: ProductsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'prefix',
                component: ProductsListComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: EmptyComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: ':category',
                        component: EmptyComponent,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

EmptyComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'GemainEmpty',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class EmptyComponent {
}
```

Handle route changes on the ListComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routerEventsSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
        }
        //Code to reload/filter list
    }
}
```

And add a router outlet on the ListComponent template.

Answer (score 4):

You could also define a redirect to a specific path:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

where `/home` is the route you want to redirect to.

`path: '**'` resolves all paths which are not defined

Comment: The paths are checked in the order they are defined.  So the `**` path would need to be **LAST**, or strategically placed.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it by using redirect,

```
const productsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
        {
            // path => '/products'
            path: '',
            redirectTo: ':category',
        },
        {
            // path => '/products/:category'
            path: ':category',
            component: ProductsListComponent
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

It's more like set one path default, unless there is a matching path.

Comment: In angular 15 and above you need to add pathMatch: 'full' along with redirectTo property.

Answer (score 2):

For problems like 'angular router optional parameter', 'angular route component reuse':

**UrlMatcher** is for creating a custom route matcher for a route pattern (which leads to your desired component). As a result, a customized route pattern is going to be handled, and the corresponding requests are handled by that component.

In the routes array,
`{ matcher: productsMatcher, component: ProductsListComponent}` is a route, just as `{ path: 'somewhere', component: SomeComponent }` that defines a route.

A matcher takes the whole url string as an array of segments. The segments can be assigned to route params, which can be read by the component.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes, UrlMatchResult, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';


const productsMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult => {
  if (segments.length === 1 && segments[0].path === 'products') {
    return {
      consumed: segments,
      posParams: {}
    }
  }
  if (segments.length === 2 && segments[0].path === 'products') {
    return {
      consumed: segments,
      posParams: {
        category: segments[1]
      }
    }
  }
  return <UrlMatchResult>(null as any);
}

const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '/products', component: ProductsListComponent },
  // { path: '/products/:category', component: ProductsListComponent },
  { matcher: productsMatcher, component: ProductsListComponent},
];
```

[angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher)

In your component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      const category = param.get('category')
      if (category) { this.loadStuff(category) }
    })
  }
```

All requests of the same url pattern are directed to this component.

As a result, (after it is created at the first request) there are no redraws/recreation of the ProductsListComponent. Thus there's no flickering when visiting `/products/:category` route from `/products` route: angular sees it as the same route, so the component won't reload.

For reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002221/using-regex-for-path-value-of-routes-in-angular2/53151993#53151993) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter/56391974#56391974)