# Route without parameter value; Angular route redirect - Can I use redirectTo to parameter path?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I'm wandering if it is possible to redirect path: ' ' to path: ':id' ? Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thank you.

```
{
  path: 'folder',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: ':id',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: ':id',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      component: DocumentsComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can do this with a path matcher function instead of specifying a static path: See https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391974/1751497

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to redirect 'folder' route to 'folder/:id' with empty 'id' parameter:

```
{
    path: 'folder',
    redirectTo: 'folder/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
    path: 'folder',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            component: DocumentsComponent,
        },
    ]
}
```

*Note that the redirect must be first.

Answer (score 3):

if you give a default id lets say 1 and `redirectTo` '1' like below it should work,

```
{
  path: 'folder',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '1',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: ':id',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      component: DocumentsComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

The `redirectTo` property must be a string, and you would need to pass a *link parameters array* with a value for the `:id` param.

It's a bit hackish, but you could redirect the empty path to a hard-coded path associated to a component that redirects to `':id'` programmatically (using `router.navigate()`)...