# Angular 6 - Dynamic Routing with Prefix

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular6, dynamic-url

I am working on an Angular Universal Application. I want to create dynamic routes with custom prefix but I am unable find any helpful documentation related with my case. Any Help will be appreciated...

**Details:**

What I have is, I have 4 pages with 4 different dynamic URLs which are:

- Home Page (`http://example.com/`)
- Category Page (`http://example.com/{category_name}`)
- Sub Category Page (`http://example.com/{category_name}/{sub_category_name}`)
- Product Page (`http://example.com/p{product_id}-{product_name}`)
- User Page (`http://example.com/user{user_id}-{user_name}`)

**What I did**

I have registered a single route to handle Home, Category and Sub Category Pages because they have same UI with dynamic category levels mentioned below,

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '**', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'Home', description: 'Homepage - quick overview.'}}
    ])
```

**Struggling:**

Now, I am unable to add the routes for Product and User Page, I am unable to understand, how to add `p` and `user` prefixs after slash and before `ids` in Product and User Pages respectively. Without these prefixs, routing is working fine.

**Examples of Required URLs for Product & User Pages**

- Product Page (http://example.com/p123-Product-Name)
- User Page (http://example.com/user123-User-Name)

I am using `@angular/router` for routing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably do this by writing a custom URL matcher, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153705/1675492.

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: you have same ui, even js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, @Yuriy to reopen this, I have already got the answer from @Ingo Bürk's comment.
The below mentioned *Gist* helped me to create routes through the regex.
https://gist.github.com/matanshukry/22fae5dba9c307baf0f364a9c9f7c115

For reference, I have added the source below,

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Matan Shukry
 * All rights reserved.
 */

import { UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, Route } from '@angular/router';

// export type UrlMatchResult = {
    // consumed: UrlSegment[]; posParams?: { [name: string]: UrlSegment };
// };

export function ComplexUrlMatcher(paramName: string, regex: RegExp) {
    return (
        segments: UrlSegment[],
        segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup,
        route: Route) => {

        const parts = [regex];
        const posParams: { [key: string]: UrlSegment } = {};
        const consumed: UrlSegment[] = [];

        let currentIndex = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
            if (currentIndex >= segments.length) {
                return null;
            }
            const current = segments[currentIndex];

            const part = parts[i];
            if (!part.test(current.path)) {
                return null;
            }

            posParams[paramName] = current;
            consumed.push(current);
            currentIndex++;
        }

        if (route.pathMatch === 'full' &&
            (segmentGroup.hasChildren() || currentIndex < segments.length)) {
            return null;
        }

        return { consumed, posParams };
    }
}
```

How to use,

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Matan Shukry
 * All rights reserved.
 */

export const UserRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserListComponent
      },
      {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("id", /[0-9]+/),
        component: UserItemComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(UserRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally a `router` needs to be able to match a certain input string (`url`) to a given pattern (`route`). You want to make sure that a **single** input does not match **multiple** patterns, otherwise the router will not know which way to move forward.

That being said, **Angular** has the concept of a `[RouteGuard][1]`. A RouteGuard (or any of its derivatives) gives hook into the routing process when a url is matched to a given route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "matcher".

See: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

I hope it helped.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

To create `http://example.com/p{product_id}-{product_name}`, we could break the product_id segment as `:product_id` and product_name segment as `:product_name`. Then you need to head to your app.routing.js routing file and set the url as:

```
{ path: 'http://example.com/p/:product_id/-/:product_name', component: ProductComponent }
```