# Angular route with limited options as param

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to understand how can I limit the options for a param in a route in Angular.

When I'm declaring a route:

```
{
  path: 'food/:name',
  component: FoodComponent,
},
```

`:name` can be anything. What I'd like to do is to limit the options to: `apple` or `orange`, etc..
and if the value is other than the available options - catch it as the 404 route (`path: '**'`).

I guess I can always verify the param at the component level, and redirect to 404 if the value isn't match.. but I thought maybe is there is a way to do that at the route level.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try resolver?

Comment: You can use url matcher as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002221/using-regex-for-path-value-of-routes-in-angular2)

Comment: You can use a `guard` for this. But it looks like you can create separate routes `food/apple` and `food/orange`. With this angular router will redirect to the 404 route if somebody tries to open something else.

Comment: @epsilon There could be a lot of available options, so create a route for each might be repetitive.

Comment: Thank you @Eldar. exactly what I was looking for!