# Conditionally Apply router reuse strategy for angular2 routes

Tags: angular

I came to know about Sticky Routes to reattach the earlier component data when navigated back to the same component.I have implemented a demo by looking at this  https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx  blog here https://plnkr.co/edit/KVlRi9PtPeOpvn8bECBi?p=preview ... Is it Possible to have the apply conditions so that `routerreusestrategy` apply only for few components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)

Answer (score 12):

You need only minor modification of the original solution: https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Add `shouldDetach` flag to your route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent, data: { shouldDetach: true } },
  ...
];
```

And modify `shouldDetach` method in `CustomReuseStrategy`:

```
public shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  return route.data && (route.data as any).shouldDetach;
}
```

Here is your plunker updated: https://plnkr.co/edit/otbZBuRmGYQXeY6b4Sfp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this helped me get conditional route reuse working!