# CustomReuseStrategy not working for lazy loaded components

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a component that is part of a module that is now being lazy loaded. The problem is that the component is re-initializing every time the route is used.

Here is my route.

```
{
    path: 'activities',
    loadChildren: () => System.import('../containers/activity-engine/activity-engine.module').then((file: any) => {
        return file.default;
    }),
    data: {
        shouldDetach: true, // Route will be resused. See CustomReuseStrategy.
        title: null
    }
},
```

Here is the route for the module being loaded.

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ActivityEngineComponent,
    data: {
        shouldDetach: true, // Route will be resused. See CustomReuseStrategy.
        title: null
    }
},
```

I am importing the following classes in app module and the lazy loaded module, and they are being applied as providers:

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomReuseStrategy } from '../../shared/router/custom-reuse-strategy';

providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
]
```

Here is my CustomReuseStrategy:

```
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

    // Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        // We can choose which routes should be resued (i.e. shouldDetach === true) 
        // (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483187/conditionally-apply-router-reuse-strategy-for-angular2-routes).
        return !!route.data && !!(route.data as any).shouldDetach;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }

}
```

Is there a was to use `CustomReuseStrategy` with lazy loaded components?

Comment: can you add code as how you are implementing `RouteReuseStrategy` in your `CustomResuseStrategy` ?

Comment: please see edited question above @MadhuRanjan

Comment: you do not need ` shouldDetach: true` where you are lazy loading children, it is needed only where you have component defined.

Comment: removing that code actually fixed the issue. If you add the answer I will check it for you.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need `shouldDetach: true` where you are lazy loading children, it is needed only where you have component defined.