# router reuse with lazy load causing error

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, angular5

I have referred this link to implement router reuse in my angular5 project that has lazyloading :
 [Angular2 doesn't work Custom Reuse Strategy with Lazy module loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383546/angular2-doesnt-work-custom-reuse-strategy-with-lazy-module-loading)
i.e. with data attribute having a custom key in the route. This works fine.
However, when I log out from my site and go back to that page, the data is unchanged and user appears logged in.

i refereed this : [How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
i dnt want to save the state after user logs in or out
at login on logout I tried clearing the handle by creating an instance of the routing.ts class and calling the storedRouteHandles.clear() method, but it doesn't get cleared.

What needs to be done?

Comment: Same where in the code you save the token and when you logout you don't clean it out

Comment: It shows it logged out on other pages. I am using router reuse on only 1component.
It also shows it logged out if i hard refresh or reload the page. It doesnt seem to enter the ngInit function or constructor of the component on the first try.

Comment: i need more code to understand the problem but search the code for the login function to get the token location then in the logout delete it.

Comment: okay i ll try that. But could you please explain this:
Does router Reuse disallow the code from entering the .ts component?

Comment: all what router Reuse is that it don't remove the component from the DOM it just hide it until you need it back that all.

Comment: thank you very much