# Should OnInit lifecycle hook run when reusing component with RouteReuseStrategy?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**Update**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673630/828547

> [...]with LazyLoaded modules, route.routeConfig.path is empty when executing shouldAttach

Using explicitly defined additional developer-defined data rather than `route.routeConfig.path` works.

**Original Question**

When implementing `RouteReuseStrategy` to provide a custom route reuse strategy, I've observed.

1. `OnInit` and the `constructor` are called when *entering* a component that has previously been stored for reuse
2. `OnDestroy` is NOT called when *leaving* a component that has previously been stored for reuse

Intuitively, it makes sense that `OnDestroy` is *not* called for a component that should be reused later on.

However, it seems counter-intuitive that the `constructor` and `OnInit` are called for components that are being reused. It's common to place initialization code in these functions, and so the component appears new each time.

There's no shortage of tutorials on `RouteReuseStrategy` ([1](https://www.auroria.io/angular-route-reuse-strategy/), [2](https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f), [3](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-toggle-caching-for-routing-components-in-angular-5a327ea87310), [4](https://www.intertech.com/angular-development-10-routereusestrategy-maintaining-component-state/)) , but I can't find anything confirming whether my observations are correct.

In the implementation of the `RouteReuseStrategy` interface below, `MyComponent` is stored for reuse. According, its `OnDestroy` hook is NOT called when navigating away from the component. However, upon **re**entering the component, its constructor and `OnInit` hook are called.

```js
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    private storedRoutes = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();

    /**
     * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
     * If shouldDetach returns true, then we need to store the route as we want to reuse later.
     * Called when leaving a route.
     */
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (!route.routeConfig?.path) {
            return false;
        }
        // Prevents the MyComponent component from being destroyed (OnDestroy not called).
        return ['my-component'].indexOf(route?.routeConfig?.path) > -1;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the detached route. Called when leaving a route.
     */
    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        if (!route.routeConfig?.path) {
            return;
        }
        const path = this.getPath(route);
        this.storedRoutes.set(path, handle);
    }

    /**
     * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be reattached.
     * If shouldAttach returns true, we want to reuse a previously stored route instead of building new components.
     * Called when entering a route.
     */
    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (!route.routeConfig?.path) {
            return false;
        }
        const path = this.getPath(route);
        return this.storedRoutes.has(path);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the previously stored route.
     */
    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        if (!route.routeConfig?.path) {
            return null;
        }
        const path = this.getPath(route);
        return this.storedRoutes.get(path) || null;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
     * Called everytime we navigate between routes.
     */
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // Reuse the route if the new route has the same config as the previous one.
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }

    private getPath(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        if (route.routeConfig !== null && route.routeConfig.path !== null) {
            return route.routeConfig?.path || "";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Questions

1. Should `constructor` and `OnInit` be called for components that are reattached (reused)?
2. If answer to 1. is "yes" - where should initialization code be placed such that it's run only when the component is NOT being reused?

**Stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9fs3tg?file=src/app

To mirror my application the stackblitz has the following module hierarchy

```
- app
  - home
    - manager
    - detail
```

Each module has routing

- `/` loads `AppComponent`
- `/home` loads `HomeComponent`
- `/home/manager` loads `ManagerComponent`
- `/home/detail` loads `DetailComponent`

The custom routing strategy reuses the `ManagerComponent` so that upon returning to it, the list of details is not re-rendered.

[image]

[image]

To recreate the issue:

1. Go to [/home/manager](https://angular-ivy-9fs3tg.stackblitz.io/home/manager)
2. Open the Console provided by Stackblitz to see the logging
3. Click on `/home/detail/1`
4. Look in the console and see that `-----> stored route with path "manager"` is logged
5. Click "back to manager" and see that `ManagerComponent.constructor` and `ManagerComponent.ngOnInit` are logged.

The logging shows that the route was attached

- `shouldAttach(manager)`
- `-----> Yes!`
- `retrieve(manager)`
- `-----> retrieved route with path "manager"`

If the route was attached, why are the constructor and `OnInit` of the manager component called?

Comment: Hey @Jack, the `constructor` and `OnInit` should not trigger on a reused route as you can see in this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upbnpo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: @mikegross Thanks for confirming. I'll create a Stackblitz and add it to my question, because I can clearly see the component being attached AND reinitialized

Comment: @mikegross I've updated my question with a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9fs3tg?file=src/app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383546/angular2-doesnt-work-custom-reuse-strategy-with-lazy-module-loading solved my problem.

Comment: I was researching this as we speak! Good thing you got it solved, it should have been obvious from the start that this was the direction to take! I learned something today :) thanks!