Angular: ngOnInit() Not Triggering After Navigating to another Component
I've implemented a component reuse strategy in Angular, and I'm applying this functionality when navigating internal back(not browser back button) navigation.
However, after navigating back and clicking on a current list item to move to another component, ngOnInit() is not triggering due to the reuse strategy. How can I ensure ngOnInit() is triggered in this case?

CustomRouteReuseStrategyService

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategyService implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private handlers: { [key: string]: () => void } = {};
  private backNavigation: boolean;

  setBackNavigation(backNavigation: boolean): void {
    this.backNavigation = backNavigation;
  }

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.backNavigation ? false : true;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handler: () => void): void {
    this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handler;
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): () => void {
    return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }
}


back navigation in header component

goBack(): void {
    console.log("Go back clicked>>>");
    // Set the back navigation flag to true
    this.customRouteReuseStrategyService.setBackNavigation(true);
    // Navigate back
    //this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
     //this.location.back();
    this.navigationService.goBack();
  }


What's happening within the goBack() Method of the NavigationService? Besides, ngOnInit is called each time the Component is initialized. Looks like You may want to look into using tick() within your goBack Method. Inject ApplicationRef eg: private _appRef = inject(ApplicationRef) and then inside your
goBack Method; invoke: this._appRef.tick()... This is only a wild Idea and involves manually triggering re-rendering but it's also likely close though...

Whats about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498489/should-oninit-lifecycle-hook-run-when-reusing-component-with-routereusestrategy

why would you want to trigger ngOnInit() again? The whole point of the ReuseStrategy is to NOT recreate the component.

ngOnInit is call when the component init, not when input change. I think in your case you need to call ngOnChanges when the input change (here new item selected from your list)

@berse2212 My whole idea is to keep a snapshot of the component for back navigation. If the user clicks on any action buttons in the current component, it should trigger ngOnInit() in another component again. Is there any other solution for this use case?

@vishnu probably - hard to tell without knowing why you need to trigger the ngOnInit again.
