# prevent video reload on router navigation

Tags: angular

I have a simple app that uses video. 
This is route to it:

```
{ path: 'video', component: VideoComponent }
```

ngOnInit

```
  this.video.nativeElement.src = videoSrc;
```

and a sample url:

```
/video?project=3
```

The user can navigate to different routes as well. Such as:

```
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
```

My problem is that when the user navigates to routes other then `video` and comes back, video file is fetched again. I would like to keep it loaded the whole time and prevent subsequent reloads.

What are my options? I've found that you can use `RouteReuseStrategy` https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy, but it appears to only be valid for activated routes.

Comment: reuse strategy is the way to go

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877958/3055401

Comment: Okay, so rewriting my app to use activated params is necessary if I want to prevent later video reloads?