# Angular 5: Route animations for navigating to the same route, but different parameters

Tags: angular5, angular-router, angular-animations

In my Angular 5 application, the user may navigate to a route which uses the same route, but with different parameters. For example, they may navigate from `/page/1` to `/page/2`.

I want this navigation to trigger the routing animation, but it doesn't. How can I cause a router animation to happen between these two routes?

(I already understand that unlike most route changes, this navigation does not destroy and create a new `PageComponent`. It doesn't matter to me whether or not the solution changes this behavior.)

[Here's a minimal app that reproduces my issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag7los)

Comment: can you provide some code on what have you done so far? or provide a code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Sure - [here's a minimal app that reproduces my issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag7los) (Thanks for the heads-up about stackblitz, by the way! Great site!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question but that's it if you're still searching.
Add this code to your app.Component.ts file.

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private _Router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._Router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
  return false;
  };
  this._Router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this._Router.navigated = false;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  });
}
```

By using this code the page is going to refresh if you clicked on the same route no matter what is the parameter you added to the route.

I hope that helps.

**Update**

As angular 6 is released with core updates you don't need this punch of code anymore just add the following parameter to your routs import.

```
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
```

This option value set to `'ignore'` by default.

**Example**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Stay up to date and happy coding.

Comment: This is an even older response! This answer pointed me in the right direction, I'll post what I ended up using myself.

Comment: as angular 6 is released i'll post an update for this.

Comment: The updated answer seems like a better solution for angular 6, which I have recently switched to. Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an update for angular 16?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom `RouteReuseStrategy` which got the job done. It's heavily based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854611/4766643).

```js
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  storedRouteHandles = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.storedRouteHandles.set(route.routeConfig.path, handle);
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this.storedRouteHandles.get(route.routeConfig.path);
  }

  // This is the important part! We reuse the route if
  // the route *and its params* are the same.
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig &&
      future.params.page === curr.params.page;
  }
}
```

[Check it out on StackBlitz!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rspzzg?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: (I used the other answer after upgrading to Angular 6 but I will leave this here for Angular 5 users.)