# angular 5.2 onSameUrlNavigation not working

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to reload my navigations in my angular 5.2 application without any success. If the params are unchanged, the angular router will ignore my navigations.

How I navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['/search', buildParamsFromSearchCriteria(criteria)]);
```

This navigates to:

```
/search;pageSize=20;page=1;orderBy=price;sortDirection=ASCENDING
```

My module config:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, enableTracing: false, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
```

Comment: Did you see that thread? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115 Apparently,it's only used torun again guards and resolvers. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Can't you just have a 'refresh' action in your component that you could call manually?

Comment: I can't have a refresh because my component only navigates with the search params. My ngrx effects listens to the router calls and  dispatches a search-action on navigation to the url. I have a temporary hack now that sets a random number at the end of the url to make it unique

Comment: Why would you route on the same url twice? You would get the same result?

Comment: The result may not be the same because the backend data may have been updated or items may have been added.

Comment: You could add one more random parameter to force refresh.

Comment: is a simple `window.location.reload(true);` an option?

Comment: @lukas-reineke I don't want to reload page. It would result in restarting my single page application.

Comment: ```router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };```

Comment: Check this solution work every times for me.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070404/angular-5-route-animations-for-navigating-to-the-same-route-but-different-para/49162885](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070404/angular-5-route-animations-for-navigating-to-the-same-route-but-different-para/49162885)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in a much simpler way. Below is a small sample code:

in routing.module: "/product/: id / details"

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from ‘@angular/router’;

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.paramsChange(params.id);
        });

    }

    // Call this method on page load
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    // Call this method on change of the param
    paramsChange(id) {
    }
```

the general explanation is ... why to destroy already existed component instance and create a new one for the same case when it means performance degradation? It is the exactly the same behavior as using routes pattern /product/:id where the same component instance is also kept for /product/5, /product/6, ...

So you should re-init the component on the base of some emitted event (resolver/guard) and not on the base of OnInit hook because of the same component instance.

Comment: I had tried this approach but in the case of navigation to the route having the same param. It won't trigger an event for the `this.route.params.subscribe(params => `

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same problem when trying to refresh a page when clicking on its associated button on the navbar.

As stated in the comments, `onSameUrlNavigation` only runs guards and resolvers, but do not reinitialize components. The interesting part is that it also triggers a navigation.

So I created an abstract class that reacts to the `NavigationEnd` event:

```js
/**
 * Abstract class that allows derived components to get refreshed automatically on route change.
 * The actual use case is : a page gets refreshed by navigating on the same URL and we want the rendered components to refresh
 */
export abstract class AutoRefreshingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public routerEventsSubscription: Subscription;
  protected router: Router;

  constructor() { 
    this.router = AppInjector.get(Router);
  }

  /**
   * Initialization behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnInit.
   * Use initialize() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
    this.routerEventsSubscription = this.router.events.filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(res => {
      this.initialize();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Destruction behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnDestroy.
   * Use destroy() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routerEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.destroy();
  }

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define an initialization behavior
   */
  abstract initialize(): void;

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define a destruction behavior
   */
  abstract destroy(): void;

}
```

AppInjector refers to this:

```js
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppInjector.get(MyService)` (whereas
 * `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(MyService)` would create a new instance
 * of the service).
 */
export let AppInjector: Injector;

/**
 * Helper to access the exported {@link AppInjector}, needed as ES6 modules export
 * immutable bindings; see http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html
 */
export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And in the AppModule:

```js
import { setAppInjector } from './app.injector';

// ...

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    setAppInjector(injector);
  }
}
```

Then I made all of my needed components extend `AutoRefreshingComponent` and implement needed functions.

Hope this late answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.navigated =false
work for me  then at ngOnInit just put this below code
this._initise = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  takeUntil(this.destroyed)
).subscribe(() => {
  this.router.navigated = false;
  console.log('initialiseInvites')
  this.initialiseInvites();
});
```