# How to activate RouteReuseStrategy only for specific routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to implement `RouteReuseStrategy` only for specific routes?

Meaning each route with children, getting its own custom implementation of `RouteReuseStrategy`, and whose methods only fire when a route in a specific 'tree' is activated.

I currently use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular) answer, but I want to expand it with the above logic if possible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Create a custom route reuse strategy

```js
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from "@angular/router";

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return route.data.shouldReuse || false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: {}): void {
    if (route.data.shouldReuse) {
      this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): {} {
    if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
    return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.data.shouldReuse || false;
  }

}
```

In your router module, implement the new strategy in the `providers` array:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomRouteReuseStategy },
  ...
]
```

Then, declare the desired route with a data property 'shouldReuse' set to true

```js
{ path: 'myPath', component: MyComponent, data: { shouldReuse: true } },
```

Only the routes with the data property `shouldReuse` set to `true` will be reused.

Comment: pure gold! short and elegant... very nice 

Comment: When i implement this solution `firstChild` of `ActivatedRoute` becomes `null`. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, i've found out why. I need to set `data: { shouldReuse: true|false }` for _all_ the path definitions. Or else firstChild will become null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by writing your own RouteReuseStrategy (CustomReuseStrategy).

To black or white list routes, you can search for a data property which you can set in the router-module under the route and then choose to attach the component (to reuse it later), or not.

**Helpful links to get you started:**

- https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-2-reuse-strategy-sample/blob/master/app/shared/router/custom-reuse-strategy.ts
- https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5
- [How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular/41515648)

Comment: This is exactly what your are not supposed to do on SO, link to external websites because those websites can go down at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll actually go read the guidelines now, makes total sense. This was a very common issue, with many explainations far better then my own - and felt sharing these, would help best. Edit: after reading the guidelines, linking external is fine, but  the most import information is referenced and given on SO (for any future readers)