How to inject RouteReuseStrategy only in specific components?
In my Angular16 standalone app I want to implement a RouteReuseStrategy and add it only to specific components. I found some solutions that implied using some extras (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156005/11615575), but I would like a different approach.
Given this implementation:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlwaysReloadRouteStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    return null; // return null, meaning no route will be reused
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false; // don't attach any stored route, force reload
  }

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false; // never detach the route, we want to force a reload
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(
    future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    return false; // don't reuse any route, always reload
  }

  store(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    handle: DetachedRouteHandle | null
  ): void {
    // don't story any route
  }
}

When trying to use it directly on the component:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-configuration-general',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterLink,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: AlwaysReloadRouteStrategy } <---- injecting it here
  ],
  templateUrl: './configuration-general.component.html'
})
export class ConfigurationGeneralComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

   onClick(): void {
     this.router.navigate([this.router.url], { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}); <--- does not work
   }
}

However, if instead of adding it at component level I do it inside main.ts like this (so basically it's applied to all routes), it works successfully:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      ...
      provideRouter(ROUTES, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules), ),
      { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: AlwaysReloadRouteStrategy }, <--- here

UPDATE
Noticed that for the first approach, if I update the `router` instance then the reload works:
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy = new AlwaysReloadRouteStrategy();
  }


Seems like you answered your own question. You cannot provide RouteReuseStrategy at the component level, that is the gist of it. The other details your provided are great workarounds and should be posted as an answer by you!

I see, will proceed then. I was really curious why I couldn't find such a solution before, but it turns out it's because it's impossible :)

@Andrei, here you have a "CustomReuseStrategy" that only change when you define in the path data:{reload:true} , but it's true, all the aplication use this "reuseStrategy"
