# Dynamic Router Reuse Strategy based on some condition

Tags: angular, router

I Implemented router reuse strategy by following this [THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)

Here all routes and components instance have been saved on every single visit. This cause some misbehaviour in our functionality. So I decided to store particular instance at particular point based on some condition like using shared service `value` or based on `property` of a component. `RouteReuseStrategy` not allowing to create any constructor.How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how effective it is but I tried to extract properties from component instance

```
store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle) {
   const componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = handle ? handle['componentRef'] : null ;
   //IF condition
     this.handlers[this.getRouteUrl(route)] = handle;
}
```