# function in constructor should not load on going back Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

I am working on Angular 7 Application and , I am facing problem on stopping  a function to call again ,where  function exist in  in constructor , which I stop calling again on navigating back to the same component

eg ->

1. We are in component A
2. we navigate and go to component B
3. when we again go to component A , **function in constructor should not load**

I tried with many ways using Angular rout , but it is not working for me

Comment: We you navigate to component B , component A get destroyed and we you go back to A is gone to construct again 

Comment: **why do you think** that constructor should not load.

Comment: Do you wanna stop the constructor (wich would be weird) ? Or do you wanna stop whats happening in the Constructor like webservices ?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes

Comment: show your routing file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular

Comment: A **Constructor** is a special type of method of a class and it will be automatically invoked when an instance of the class is created. A `class` may contain at least one `constructor` declaration. If a class has no constructor, a constructor is provided automatically. It's used to allocate memory for the objects of the class

Having said that, the `constructor` will get executed if the `component` class loads or reloads.Try to execute those functions conditionally ( make use of route `params` or something to identify reload route).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have an initialization logic who supposed to happen only once, so about telling us, once perwhat ?

What do this logic ? In fact, we will need more information to help you on the design level.

What are you trying to achieve ?