# How to implement RouteReuseStrategy only when user goes back (history)?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular 2 project where I have implemented a custom-reuse-strategy that stores the detached route and reuse them if they already exist.

It's good, but I would like to use this mechanism only if user click on navigator go back button, and not if the user click directly on some links in my page or menu.

The purpose is that if user is coming from go back button, the route will be displayed has he left, but if user click on a link or menu, the page will be reloaded and data from server will be fetched again!

I tried to see if there is the information in the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` that the user is coming from history and not directly from a link (with `router.navigate`) but I can't see nothing.

Is there a way to achieve what I would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the back button is pressed doing:

```js
constructor(location: LocationStrategy) {
  location.onPopState(() => {
    console.log('Back button pressed!');
    console.log(window.location);
  });
}
```

You should add `@Injectable()` to inject the `LocationStrategy`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can I use that in a custom RouteReuseStrategy, I can't inject any services in it otherwise I have an error like :

`Can't resolve all parameters for CustomReuseStrategy: (?).`

Comment: @Amo add `@Injectable()` on your `CustomReuseStrategy`, it should work. If it is, I'll update my answer!

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody wonders how *exactly* to pull this off, here is some more detailed code.

Like @youri wrote, you add the code below in your `route-custom-strategy.ts`:

```
@Injectable()

export class CustomRouteReuseStategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    constructor(location: LocationStrategy) {
        location.onPopState(() => {
            this.back = true
            console.log('Back button pressed!', this.back);
        });
    }

    // Back-navigation monitoring
    back: boolean = false

   // ------------ Your RouteReuseStrategy code ---------------
}
```

Remember to add the `Injectable()`.

Now that you have set the `back` variable as a flag for when the user navigated back (or forward - remember that `onPopState()` fires for all pop states), we need to make sure that `shouldAttach` fires only on back (or forward) navigation.

I assume that your `shouldAttach` code looks something like this:

```
shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

    const storedObject = this.storedRoutes[id];
    const canAttach = !!route.routeConfig && !!storedObject;
    if (!canAttach) return false

    const paramsMatch = this.compareObjects(route.params, storedObject.snapshot.params);
    const queryParamsMatch = this.compareObjects(route.queryParams, storedObject.snapshot.queryParams);
   
    return paramsMatch && queryParamsMatch;
}
```

So you simply need to add a parameter that checks for our `this.back` boolean value and a line of code to reset that value to `false` in order to catch the next back navigation.
The above code becomes:

```
shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

    const storedObject = this.storedRoutes[id];
    const canAttach = !!route.routeConfig && !!storedObject;

    if (!canAttach || !this.back)  {
       this.back = false
       return false;
    }

    this.back = false
    const paramsMatch = this.compareObjects(route.params, storedObject.snapshot.params);
    const queryParamsMatch = this.compareObjects(route.queryParams, storedObject.snapshot.queryParams);
   
    return paramsMatch && queryParamsMatch;
}
```

That's it. Now you will only reuse the stored page on back/forward navigation and a fresh component will be loaded when you navigate by clicking a route.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is based on the CustomReuseStrategy by McGiogen, See [How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)).

What worked for me was creating a new service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingService {
  public isNavigatingBack: boolean;
}
```

In app.component.ts adding:

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationStart)).subscribe(() => {
  const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
  const isNavigatingBack = navigation.trigger === 'popstate';
  this.routingService.isNavigatingBack = isNavigatingBack;
});
```

And in shouldAttach adding:

```
if (!canAttach || !this.routingService.isNavigatingBack) {
  return false;
}
```