# Angular - Detect if stored components have been reattached or detached

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I implemented a custom route strategy (more or less copied, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515648/11915263)) to cache already visited routes. Now I want to detect if a component inside a cached route has been reattached or detached.

For example: I want to resume a video inside a component if a cached route has been reattached.

Basically I can compare the route on which it has been initialized and subscribe to route changes. But I am currently struggling on how to implement this the best possible way because this seems to be implemented in every component.

I was looking for Lifecycle Hook [methods](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) but it seems that none of them are executed on my route strategy.

Comment: An idea: Use a subject in your custom strategy and when the `retrieve` method is called, make that subject emit a new value with the component that you're interested in. You can get that component by searching in it `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.

Comment: But I need to know the component inside my route strategy.

Comment: I could iterate through every child component and emit an event. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, try to `console.log` the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.