# For Angular 11, How to remember previous state like scroll position and data on route change?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular11

I made a simple [Angular app](https://angular-ivy-vsykgt.stackblitz.io) with three routes (home, hello, detail). Home contains long text with scrolling.

After scrolling little bit, click hello or detail link, then click the home link again.

I want to keep it where I left off and avoid scrolling back or making ajax call if any. In other words serve cached page.

Tried various solutions like `scrollPositionRestoration:enabled` or implement [custom routereusestrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular) but its not working. Not sure what the issue is? Or if I am totally off.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I was able to get the component state to work using [compareObjects code block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57425744/209609). Now just need the scrolling to work

Comment: Why not save the information on a service?

Comment: @OwenKelvin thanks, that's going to be my fallback solution to save scroll position in service. I am trying to find a built in solution and see why scrollPositionRestoration is not working

Comment: `scrollPositionRestoration` is for backwards navigation, and for the scroll of the whole page. You can see how it works if you remove the fixed `height` from the `div`, scroll down in the page, change to another route and use your browser's "back" button. See the reference for `scrollPositionRestoration`: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration

Comment: @Cem you are right, removing height from div worked! Now i need to see if i can do scrolling for inner div