# Angular component reloads when navigating

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Routes for my Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ":level1/:level2/:level3", component: CategoriesComponent },
  { path: ":level1/:level2", component: CategoriesComponent},
  { path: ":level1", component: CategoriesComponent},
  { path: "", component: CategoriesComponent },
];
```

the Categories component Generates some links like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="['category1']" [relativeTo]="activatedRoute">My Link</a>
```

the `ngOnInit` & `ngOnDestroy` are called each time it navigates between those routes.

What I need is the component to stay mounted and not re-init each time.

Stackblitz link to illustrate the difference between using QueryParameters and RouteParameters: [Angular example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ar1nmq?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

**NOTE: Dont suggest RouteReuseStrategy: that isn't the answer we are looking for. I have another angular application that doesn't reload the component between routes. And this is the official expected behaviour.**

Comment: Did you tried using RouteReuseStrategy?

Comment: No. I dont understand why the component is being Reloaded. This does not seem normal. Am I using Routers incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dive into a `RouteReuseStrategy` and create your custom strategy with saving touched pages
[Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/BaseRouteReuseStrategy)

Answer (score 0):

`RouteReuseStrategy` allows you to tell Angular not to destroy a component, but in fact to save it for re-rendering at a later date. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515648/15439733

Comment: No.
But Angular can see that the same Component name is used for both routes, so then why is it reloading it?