# Angular14 Save nested component state to reuse it in another route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a dashboard page in my app (`/dashboard`) with a `DashboardComponent` that uses, in its template, a nested `ItemsListComponent` component.
I also have another route in my app (`/items`) that only uses the `ItemsListComponent`.

How do I save the state of the `ItemsListComponent` so that its reused in both the `/dashboard` and the `/items` pages ?

Currently, I'm using a custom `RouteReuseStrategy` class ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515648/23455986)) to save the state of components on selected routes. The `ItemsListComponent` state is successfully saved on both the `/dashboard` and the `/items` pages, but these are two different instances of the `ItemsListComponent` with separate states, even if both have the same key, as on the `/dashboard` route, the `RouteReuseStrategy` methods are only triggered for the `DashboardComponent` (that contains the `ItemsListComponent`).

I understand that `RouteReuseStrategy` only saves the states of **routes** and not components, so I'm not even sure that what I'm asking for is possible, but perhaps someone found a hacky way to make it work.

Comment: Use a service that is provided in the both the dashboard and items pages that has something with the current state.